# Why does the constructor returns an empty vector?

Tags: c++

I am working on an end-of-year project for my university CS course, but I have been stuck at this one function for several days, I haven't been able to get much help, and my time is starting to run out. Can you please help me fixing this?

The function definition in hpp contains a constructor:

```
class Grille {
    vector<vector<Place>> grille;

    public:

    //Constructor
    Grille();
```

The constructor is implemented like this:

```
Grille::Grille() {
    vector<vector<Place>> grille(20);

    vector<Place> vp(20);
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++) {vp[j] = Place{Coord{i+1,j+1}};}
        grille[i] = vp;
        //cout << grille[i].size() << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the << operator for Grille (it's an ant simulation so the grid needs to be visualized with some properties):

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Grille& g) {
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++) {
            char o = '.';
            if(g.grille[i][j].contientNid()) {o = 'N';}
            else if(g.grille[i][j].contientSucre()) {o = 'S';}
            else if(g.grille[i][j].numeroFourmi() != 1) {o = 'f';}
            out << o;
        }
        out << endl;
    }
    out << endl;
    return out;
}
```

And here is the test thing I use (it's Doctest, though I'm mainly using it as a main function):

```
TEST_SUITE_BEGIN("Grille");
TEST_CASE("Testing Grille") {
    Grille g = Grille();
    cout << g.getGrilleSize() << endl;
    cout << 't' << endl;
    cout << g;
}
TEST_SUITE_END;
```

The size of grille in the constructor (commented cout at line 8) is correctly 20, but the size after the constructor (cout in the test thing, line 4) shows 0. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `vector<vector<Place>> grille(20);` is defining a new vector object and hiding the member `this->grille`. Use `grille.resize(20);` instead, or put `grille(20)` in the initializer list.

Comment: You declare a function local vector, you don't change your member data. Utilizing the ctor initialization section avoids this error entirely.

Comment: Your constructor creates a new local object named `grille` and initializes it, instead of the class member.

Comment: You declare  local variable `vector<vector<Place>> grille(20);` in your constructor, populate that, and it gets destroyed when the constructor exits. This local variable is, in no way, related to the variable declared as a member of the class.

Comment: *What did I do wrong?*  You did not enable your compiler warnings, which would have pointed out that your local variable is shadowing the member variable of the same name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor is declaring a local variable `vector<vector<Place>> grille(20);` that is shadowing (hiding) the member variable `vector<vector<Place>> grille;`.

You should remove the local variable, and instead initialize the member variable `grille` via the constructor's member initialization list.

```cpp
Grille::Grille() : grille(20) {

    vector<Place> vp(20);
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++) {vp[j] = Place{Coord{i+1,j+1}};}
        grille[i] = vp;
        //cout << grille[i].size() << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`vector<vector<Place>> grille(20);` declares `grille` as a local variable in the constructor. It shadows the data member of the same name. Don't declare another vector of the same name and you will be fine:

```
Grille::Grille() {
    grille.resize(20);

    vector<Place> vp(20);
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++) {vp[j] = Place{Coord{i+1,j+1}};}
        grille[i] = vp;
        //cout << grille[i].size() << endl;
    }
}
```

Or rather, use the member initialization list. For complex construction of members, you can use private static or free functions:

```
std::vector<Place> init_vect() { .... }

Grille::Grille() : grille(init_vect()) {}
```

PS: constructors don't "return vectors", they construct objects.